# Checking number of KSH script arguments

Tags: ksh

When `myscript` is executed with the following arguments it fails with error 255 (below)

```
         1     2     3                4       5     6     7
myscript value value /my/path/to/file my_file /tmp/ value value
```

Checking number of passed arguments

```
if [ ${#} -ne 7 ]
echo ${#}          // Actually prints 7
then
    echo "ERROR 255: Must provide the following 7 parameters:
                   one two three four five six seven"
    exit 255
fi
```

So ... If the number is not 7, exit, but do tell what the number is .. 7.

Has the world gone mad? :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you sure you don't have a typo in your question?

```
echo ${#}          // Actually prints 7
if [ ${#} -ne 7 ]
then
    echo "ERROR 255: Must provide the following 7 parameters:
                   one two three four five six seven"
    exit 255
fi
```

Having the `echo ${#}` in between the `if [ ... ]` and the `then` is a syntax error, and makes my ksh blow up ;-) Otherwise I think your code looks correct.

But why not use newer ksh math evaluation features (maybe this will fix your problem).

```
echo ${#}          // Actually prints 7
if (( ${#} != 7 )) ; then
    echo "ERROR 255: Must provide the following 7 parameters:
                   one two three four five six seven"
    exit 255
fi
```

I hope this helps.